# UILabel could not display correctly in the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

[the original pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC14E.jpg)

[after i scrolled the tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIMeG.jpg)

the green Label is a custom label,i use autolayout(masnory) in the tableview for the cell,
but there is something wrong with the cell that the greenlabel on the cell could not display correctly .  but when i scrolled the cell out of the screen,once it appears again,everything is ok.
i have tried some methods such as call [self setNeedsLayout] in the configure cell methods ,but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Click `storyboard` and find your label and click it later look at bottom side  click `Resolve Auto Layout Issues` and choose -> `Add missing constraints` or `Update constraints` will add auto layer constraints and will look good.

Thanks